# Compile error : Directory has same name as c++ standard header <list>

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, makefile

I am getting the following compile error for a file in my project :

> Flags.h:4:16: error: ../../somepath/list: Is a directory

The error is due to there being an include like `#include <list>` in the Flags.h file at that line no. and I have a directory by the name of *list* at the path `../../somepath/` and this path is the include paths in Makefile.

(There are a lot of other files in Flags.h's directory that need `../../somepath/` for there includes)

According to me renaming the directory *list* is the way to resolve the error, but that involves a lot of rework.

So is there any other proper and easier way of solving the issue, such that ,the project being ongoing, I do not face this issue in future also ?

Comment: If you're using gcc, take a look at "-iqoute" option ( http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the include path, so that the location of the STL will be before your `../../somepath` directory. This way the preprocessor should find the "correct" `list`, before even starting to search in your `../../somepath`

Comment: The gcc docs say the following :
** All the directories named by -I are searched, in left-to-right order, before the default directories. The only exception is when dir is already searched by default. In this case, the option is ignored and the search order for system directories remains unchanged.**
So the default directories are searched before what I specify. To avoid this if i use the compiler option -nostdinc, is that the right way of doing it ?

Comment: Looks like it should work. However, this is not really what this option is meant for. Meaning, in this scenario, it may not do do what you expect it to. IMHO, if you have to start going into these corners, it may be worth taking the time, and changing the name of the "list" directory. It mat save you much more time in the future.